# Excessive request on php application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a big problem in a php application. Every time a click on a menu button on my application the number of GET requests to jquery-1.11.1.min.js increases by 2.

An example:

A have a button named process entry. That button calls that following ajax request

```
                $('#btn_process_entry').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process_entry.php",
                    dataType: "html",            
                        success: function(response){
                            $("#general_use_div").html(response).fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                        });
                    });
```

The file process_entry.php returns the follow html content

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax_functions.js"></script>
 <br><br>
 <h1 align="center">Processar Ficha</h1>
 <form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table_form">
        <tr><td align="center">CÓDIGO DE BARRAS</td>              <td><input type="text" id="in_process_entry_bar_code" required></td>
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-table" id="process_entry_button" value="Validar"></td></tr>
    </table>
 </form>
<div id="process_entry_result_div">
</div>
```

I know that excessive requests are caused by the script on line 1, that script contains the ajax request above and some others. But if i remove that line and add it my main.php file (to be loaded just once) the button `id="process_entry_button"` on line 7 stop working.

How can I load a JavaScript file just once and use it for all AJAX requests on my application, avoiding a reload every time?

Answer (score 1):

should disable the listener before, with :

```
$('#btn_process_entry').off("click");
$('#btn_process_entry').on("click", function(){
    ...
});
```